# Facebook Pixel events log issue

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-marketing-api

I am tryingto add ***Facebook Pixel Events*** in my Flutter Web app using the API structure: *https://graph.facebook.com/App-ID/activities?event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS&application_tracking_enabled=1&advertiser_tracking_enabled=1&advertiser_id=Advertiser-ID*. I want to know where I can view the events that are logged. Our setup also includes **Branch.io**, a **Facebook Ad Manager Account**, and a **Facebook Business Manager Account**, all interconnected. Some events are already being logged on the **Facebook panel** through **Branch.io**, but when we use the mentioned API, the events do not appear in the logs. May be I am doing anything wrong or implementing the wrong API. Any **assistance** with this matter would be greatly appreciated!